# iOS 7 camera burst mode

Tags: ios, camera, uiimagepickercontroller

Is it possible to do a burst mode from an app?
I'm using UIImagePickerController, however, unlike the "camera" app from the iOS, when I click on the grey button, it only takes 1 picture.
Is it possible to do burst mode? Or is it only available to the "camera" app?

Thank you,
Tee

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll need to use AVFoundation instead of `UIImagePickerController` for that. With that approach, you get a continuous video feed from the camera, and can capture as many images as you want, for example, using a timer.

Comment: Perfect, thanks @BlackRider! Definitely point me in the right direction.